# Not able to select WpfMenu Button inside WpfTable

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft, uft14

I need to perform Right Click in the Middle of WpfTable, then WpfMenu appears and I want to select a particular Option from it. 
See the Screenshot for more details:-

[image]

Here is Code I am trying:-

```
Function IncidentCancellAllActions()
    Dim Rowcnt
    Rowcnt = SwfWindow("VisionCommandClient").SwfObject("VisionCC_Incident_ActionsTab_SWO").WpfWindow("VisionCC_Incident_ActionsTab_WpfWin").WpfTable("VisionCC_Incident_ActionsTab_WpfTable").RowCount
    If Rowcnt > 0 Then
        SwfWindow("VisionCommandClient").SwfObject("VisionCC_Incident_ActionsTab_SWO").WpfWindow("VisionCC_Incident_ActionsTab_WpfWin").WpfTable("VisionCC_Incident_ActionsTab_WpfTable").ActivateCell
        SendFromKeyboard("1-SHFT-F10")
        wait 5
        'SwfWindow("VisionCommandClient").WpfWindow("VisionCC_ResourceStatusList_WpfWin_2").WpfMenu("VisionCC_Action_WPM").Select "Cancel All"
        msgbox SwfWindow("VisionCommandClient").WpfWindow("VisionCC_ResourceStatusList_WpfWin_2").WpfMenu("VisionCC_Action_WPM").ShowContextMenu
        SwfWindow("VisionCommandClient").WpfWindow("VisionCC_ResourceStatusList_WpfWin_2").WpfMenu("VisionCC_Action_WPM").Select "Cancel All"
        wait 2
    Else
    Exit Function
    End If  
End Function
```

After right Click, It is not clicking on WpfMenu option "Cancell All".

Comment: what all methods have you tried till now - to start with, are you able to highlight it ? if so then simplest thing you can try is use wait() after "Showcontextmenu". other thing you may try is arrow keys by sendkeys method

Comment: @Pranav I am not able to highlight it. When I do right Click, The Next line Code doesn't get executed and msgbox iis showing blank.

Comment: now that we narrowed it down - try different object identification methods so that you can identify the 'wpfmenu'. Also why dont you use ".click ,,, micrightbtn" method ?

Comment: Were this for a `Browser` application, I would suggest changing from Browser events to Mouse events using `Settings.WebPackage("ReplayType")` but I don't know if there's an equivalent `Wpf` setup...

Comment: @Dave No this is wpf Application

Comment: @Roger why do you have WPF objects inside of SWF objects, I've never seen them mixed and matched like that. I am used to seeing WpfWindow().WpfTable()

Comment: Hmmm. HP-UFT struggles with menu items... is it because of hidden text . I was able to select a menu item "Edit" but not an item "GeoTag From Map" my menu items seem to include a trailing space but even with a space did not match.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem and currently working around the problem using '.Type' method:

```
WpfWindow("MyWindow").WpfButton("Item-Menu").ShowContextMenu
WpfWindow("MyWindow").WpfMenu("List-Menu").Exist(1)
menuItems = WpfWindow("MyWindow").WpfMenu("List-Menu").GetVisibleText
menuItems = replace(menuItems, chr(13),"")
for each menuItem in split(menuItems,chr(10))
    WpfWindow("SAP Work Manager").WpfMenu("List-Menu").Type micDwn
    Wait 0,400 
    If instr(1, menuItem, "MenuItemToClick") > 0 Then 'replace MenuItemToClick with the menu item text.
        Exit for
    End If
next
WpfWindow("SAP Work Manager").WpfMenu("List-Menu").Type micReturn
```

This works as long as the order of menu items doesn't change. Waits are included because ive noticed HP-UFT doesn't check that the object is fully loaded before doing the next task.